# I get an error when trying to create a kind Cluster Domain Claim in version networking.internal.knative.dev/v1alpha1

Tags: kubernetes, knative

I have installed microk8s version 1.21, then try to create a "Cluster Domain Claim", I get this error "no matches for kind Cluster Domain Claim in version Networking.internal.knative.dev/v1alpha1". I searched in the CRD but I don't know how to identify in which CRD search.

Anyone can help me?

This is my YAML file:

```
    apiVersion: networking.internal.knative.dev/v1alpha1
    kind: ClusterDomainClaim
      metadata:
        name: taxo.com
    spec:
      namespace: taxo
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Knative as well as Microk8s? Installation instructions are here: https://knative.dev/docs/admin/install/; there's also a [quickstart](https://knative.dev/docs/getting-started/) that uses [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) if you're not attached to microk8s.

You can use `kubectl api-resources` to see whether you have the Knative resources installed. For example, I have:

```
$ kubectl api-resources
NAME                  SHORTNAMES   APIVERSION                                  NAMESPACED   KIND
...
clusterdomainclaims   cdc          networking.internal.knative.dev/v1alpha1    false        ClusterDomainClaim
...
```

Comment: I ran your recommendation, but the clusterdomainclaim is not listed. 
I installed knative with the command "microk8s enable knative", on microk8s (theoretically) this installs all knative options. I guess there is something additional that I need to do.

Comment: Depending on your version, you may need to install serving-default-domain.yaml from https://github.com/knative/serving/releases